# Create a calculation program that will be displayed by the browser

Tags: javascript

My program looks good to me but the retuned value is "undefinied" ... do you understand why?

```
function addition(nombreA,nombreB){
    return nombreA + nombreB;
}

function soustraction(nombreA,nombreB){
    return nombreA - nombreB;
}

function multiplication(nombreA,nombreB){
    return nombreA * nombreB ;
}

function division(nombreA,nombreB){
    return nombreA / nombreB ;
}


do {
    var calculChoice = prompt("What do you want to do ?\n\n 1 - Addition\n 2 - Soustraction\n 3 - Multiplication\n 4 - Division");
}while(calculChoice != 1 && calculChoice != 2 && calculChoice != 3 && calculChoice != 4);

console.log(calculChoice);



do {
    var premierNombre  = prompt("entrez votre premier nombre");
    var deuxiemeNombre = prompt("entrez votre second nombre");
} while (isNaN(premierNombre)||isNaN(deuxiemeNombre));

console.log(premierNombre,deuxiemeNombre);


switch(calculChoice) {
    case 1:
        var resultat = addition(premierNombre,deuxiemeNombre);
        break;

     case 2:
        resultat = soustraction(premierNombre,deuxiemeNombre);
        break;
        
    case 3:
        resultat = multiplication(premierNombre,deuxiemeNombre);
        break;

    case 4:
        resultat = division(premierNombre,deuxiemeNombre);
       break;
    
}

alert(`voici le résultat = ${resultat}`);
```

The switch statement will determine which calculation to perform by writing (1,2,3,4).

The first instruction (do while) allows you to enter the numbers 1,2,3,4. If the user does not write these numbers, the instruction executes again.

In the second statement (do while), if the user does not enter a number, it executes again.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prompt()` function returns the result as a string, and not as a number. So you must convert each to integer using `parseInt(number)`. If you don't do that, both your operator and the numbers are strings.

```
do {
    var calculChoice = parseInt(prompt("What do you want to do ?\n\n 1 - Addition\n 2 - Soustraction\n 3 - Multiplication\n 4 - Division"));
} while(calculChoice != 1 && calculChoice != 2 && calculChoice != 3 && calculChoice != 4);

console.log(calculChoice);

do {
    var premierNombre  = parseInt(prompt("entrez votre premier nombre"));
    var deuxiemeNombre = parseInt(prompt("entrez votre second nombre"));
} while (isNaN(premierNombre)||isNaN(deuxiemeNombre));
```

Answer (score 0):

change your switch by:

```
switch(parseInt(calculChoice))) {
case 1:
    var resultat = addition(premierNombre,deuxiemeNombre);
    break;

 case 2:
    resultat = soustraction(premierNombre,deuxiemeNombre);
    break;
    
case 3:
    resultat = multiplication(premierNombre,deuxiemeNombre);
    break;

case 4:
    resultat = division(premierNombre,deuxiemeNombre);
   break;
    
}
```

calculChoice is a string, and yu need parse to int

Answer (score 0):

Resultat is also declared in the first switch statement case and it cant be used outside of that. You need to declare resultat before the switch statement.

```
let resultat=''
switch(calculChoice) {
  case 1:
        resultat = addition(premierNombre,deuxiemeNombre);
        break;
     case 2:
        resultat = soustraction(premierNombre,deuxiemeNombre);
        break;
    case 3:
        resultat = multiplication(premierNombre,deuxiemeNombre);
        break;
    case 4:
        resultat = division(premierNombre,deuxiemeNombre);
       break;
}
```